# Uniform int32 Distribution

Tags: c++, uniform-distribution

Is there any way to get uniform `int32_t` distribution without a warning?
I use this `uniform_int_distribution<int32_t>` in my code but I get a warning:

```
54988961.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
54988961.cpp:6:64: warning: overflow in conversion from ‘double’ to ‘int’ changes value from ‘1.0e+10’ to ‘2147483647’ [-Woverflow]
     std::uniform_int_distribution<std::int32_t> unif(1,std::pow(10,10));
                                                        ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
```

This is exactly my code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::int32_t> unif(1,std::pow(10,10));
}
```

Comment: Please show the code in question. Your usage of `uniform_int_distribution` is incorrect, but it's not clear exactly what you did wrong. Please take a moment to read [MCVE] to learn about providing a helpful example.

Comment: Please take the time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54988961/edit) the question accordingly. Please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and give sample inputs, outputs and the error messages you get, if any. This will help us to determine what is going on and improve your chances to get an answer.

Comment: pow(10,10) doesn't fit in an 32 bit int.

Comment: I thought int32_max was 2,13*10^10

Comment: 32bit signed int maximum is 2^31-1. which is less than a quarter of 10^10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pow(10, 10)
```

This is `10000000000`, an `int32` can only hold `2147483647` (`2^31 - 1`). You should use `int64_t` if you want to be able to store your `pow(10, 10)`.

Since your min value is `1` you could also just go for its unsigned counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

The use of a large double value ([`pow()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow)) for an integer argument causes this warning in the [constructor of `uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/uniform_int_distribution).

Use an int constant instead. If you need a range that doesn’t fit in an `int32_t` then use an `int64_t` template argument.